# Symfony, how to render and save use form

Tags: arrays, json, forms, symfony

Imagine I have an Article entity, and in this entity have a report attribute which is a json_array type.

Json_array's data like `{"key1":"value1","ke2":"value2",...}`.

Now I don't know how to use symfony form to render and save these json_array like other normal attribute(e.g.,title).

I searched many articles but I haven't find a clear way to realize it.

```
class Article
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var array
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="report", type="json_array")
     */
    private $report;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on it. It sounds like you need a custom form type in a collection and a transformer. The idea is that you create a custom form type to house your key/value pairs, let's call it `KeyValueType`. Next you want to add this type to your `ArticleType` using a `CollectionType` as a wrapper. In order to turn your json to a useable data structure for the form and vice versa a transformer is used.

The `KeyValueType` class:

```php
class KeyValueType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm($builder, $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('key')
            ->add('value');
    }
}
```

The `ArticleType` class:

```
class ArticleType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm($builder, $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('report', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => KeyValueType::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
            ]);

        $builder->get('report')
            ->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
                function ($reportJson) {
                    // $reportJson has the structure {"key1":"value1","ke2":"value2",...}
                    if ($reportJson == null) {
                        return null;
                    }

                    $data = [];
                    foreach (json_decode($reportJson, true) as $key => $value) {
                        $data[] = ['key' => $key, 'value' => $value];
                    }

                    return $data;
                },
                function ($reportArray) {
                    // $reportArray has the structure [ [ 'key' => 'key1', 'value' => 'value1'], [ 'key' => 'key2', 'value' => 'value2'] ]
                    if ($reportArray == null) {
                        return null;
                    }

                    $data = [];
                    foreach ($reportArray as $report) {
                        $data[$report['key']] = $report['value'];
                    }

                    return json_encode($data);
                }
            ));
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code. I found when edit the form ,the report data can't be load from the database.Another question is I also want the key label  can display in the form. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @jmz If the json is not correctly decoded from the database field to the form field you need debug what is happening in the first closure of the callback transformer. Concerning your second question you need to create another question on SO.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! You provide me a good idea. And I have solved this question.I have created the  second question for another post.

Comment: The scond question is here. Looking forward to your reply.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37520112/symfony-render-json-array-entity-type-and-save-using-form